# jQuery hover effect doesn't work in Google Chrome on some computers

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, browser

Here is a link to what I am working on

The problem I am having is with mouseover(hover) effects in the navigation with the Chrome browser. It would seem that jquery is working fine for all other browsers and not chrome.

http://squ4reone.com/domains/ottawakaraoke/index.php

But here is the kicker, I have tried it on 12 different computers and they all showed the site fine, and only 2 computers ( which include the client's ) have issues displaying the navigation on the left.

Does anyone have an idea as to what is going on?

Comment: What exactly is the issue? What do you want to happen? What's happening instead?

Comment: What do you mean when you refer to the "client's"?

Comment: The client he is doing the site for

Comment: I'm not seeing a significant difference between Chrome and IE.

Comment: Can you post a pritn screen of the error and also provide the version and operating environment when the error occurs. (look fine here in chrome)

Answer (score 3):

You should consider solving this with CSS instead of changing the class based on mouseover.

If you change you CSS:

```
.inactive{
    font-size:115%;
    margin-top:3%;
    padding:1%;
}

.active{
    text-decoration:none;
    background:#e1edff;
    font-size:115%;
    margin-top:3%;
    padding:1%;
}
```

To:

```
.menu-element{
    font-size:115%;
    margin-top:3%;
    padding:1%;
}

.menu-element:hover {
    text-decoration:none;
    background:#e1edff;
}
```

Then you should get consistent behavior across different browsers by removing the code that switches the CSS class based on mouseover/leave and instead setting it to `.menu-element` for all elements.

**edit:** As @iGanja pointed out below, I didn't notice some of the functionality, namely that the menu items should be highlighted when hovering the section belonging to the menu item.

I still suggest doing the mouse over effect for the menu itself in CSS, and instead removing the container ID from the events:

```
$('#home').mouseenter(function(){
    $('li#NAVhome').removeClass('inactive').addClass('active');
});

$('#home').mouseleave(function(){
    $('li#NAVhome').removeClass('active').addClass('inactive');
});

//faqs div      
$('#faqs').mouseenter(function(){
    $('li#NAVfaqs').removeClass('inactive').addClass('active');
});
$('#faqs').mouseleave(function(){
    $('li#NAVfaqs').removeClass('active').addClass('inactive');
}); 

//book div
$('#book').mouseenter(function(){
    $('li#NAVbook').removeClass('inactive').addClass('active');
});
$('#book').mouseleave(function(){
    $('li#NAVbook').removeClass('active').addClass('inactive');
});

//connect div
$('#connect').mouseenter(function(){
    $('li#NAVconnect').removeClass('inactive').addClass('active');
});
$('#connect').mouseleave(function(){
    $('li#NAVconnect').removeClass('active').addClass('inactive');
});
```

This will make the menu effect more reliable, while retaining the hovering effect when mousing over sections. You might be able to shorten the code by using `.toggleClass()` instead of an `if..else` construction. (http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/)

Comment: I was thinking along the same line, why jQuery...

Comment: I also noticed that when you click on the item (So it scrolls to the part of the page) the items disapear... again in chrome. so as the logo you have to select them or mouse over them for them to apear again

Answer (score 1):

When trying to debug issues like this, it's always best to make sure your code validates.

You can check that here: http://validator.w3.org/

From running a validation on your site, it looks like you're missing the required attribute: type on your script tags.

Try changing your code to the following:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        ...
```

For bonus points you can refactor your mouseovers.

e.g. Instead of this:

```
$('#home, li#NAVhome').mouseleave(function(){
    $('li#NAVhome').removeClass('active').addClass('inactive');
});
```

Do this:

```
$("ul.nav li").hover(function() {
    $(this).removeClass("inactive").addClass("active");
}, function() {
    $(this).removeClass("active").addClass("inactive");
});
```

Comment: Initially I also asked "why jQuery?" like chirs-mv, but as I see they are changing classes of other elements NOT hovered over, this is the better solution and answers the question.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is going to sound a bit obvious but **does your client have JavaScript enabled**? This can be found in Chrome under Settings/Advanced Settings/Privacy/Content Settings/JavaScript.

The answer by **chris-mv** to use CSS instead of JavaScript is a better solution than using JQuery.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

It looks like this when you click one item